# How do I avoid calling Apollo Server's nested resolver when the field is already filled in parent resolver?

Tags: server, graphql, apollo

I need to return an object to the resolver, but so that the nested resolvers are not executed. Otherwise, when registering, you need to return user data, and they are also returned in nested resolvers, but there is a check by header, and when registering, no auth headers come in, and accordingly a crash occurs, otherwise I have already returned the required field in the register mutation so ApolloServer doesn't care, it still calls nested resolvers.

So far, I'm doing this: in the nested resolver, I check if parent already has such a field, then return it. But in each resolver it is necessary to do this, it is somehow too ugly, a lot of the same type of code. Feeling that I do not fully know the Apollo Server documentation

Comment: show some code fragments

Comment: @xadm
**Schema:**

type Mutation {
    register(email: String!, password: String!): AuthResult!
}

type AuthResult {
    account: Account!
    token: String!
}

type Account {
    billingBalance: Float!
}

**Resolvers:**

Mutation: {
register: async (parent, {email, password, userType}, {prisma}) => {
...
 return {
     account: {
         billingBalance: 123
     },
     token: 'qwe'
 };
}}

Account: {
    billingBalance: async (parent, _, {user, prisma}) => {
        return 777;
    }
```

This code will always return billingBalance==777

Comment: update the question, illustrate **all** your text statements with relevant code fragments - why headers? why crash? why balance returned in register? still unclear/too abstract